# Regex - Use Regular Expression to swap two different tags with contents

Tags: regex, tags, swap

I would like a regular expression that will swap specific tags around:

from

```
    <comment>some comment</comment>
    <name>some name</name>
```

to

```
    <name>some name</name>
    <comment>some comment</comment>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ^(<comment>.*?</comment>).*?\n.*?(<name>.*?</name>)$

    $2 \n $1
```